# Eating Candy in the Correct Order

Tags: code-golf, sorting

When it comes to eating candy, I hold myself to higher standards than the typical layperson.  There is a delicate balance between "mixing it up" and "saving the best for last."

In this challenge, you will be given a string of characters in which each character represents a piece of candy.  Different characters (case-sensitive) represent different types of candy. Your program must then determine the correct order of candy consumption, based on the procedure below. You can write either a complete program (STDIN/STDOUT) or a named function to accomplish this task.

Let's say that my candy stash is `oroybgrbbyrorypoprr`.  First, I sort the candy into piles of the same type, with larger quantities at the top, using lower ASCII character values as a tie-breaker.

```
rrrrrr
oooo
bbb
yyy
pp
g
```

Then, I take each row of candy and equally-space them along an interval.  For example, if there are 3 pieces of candy, one is placed 1/3 of the way, 2/3 of the way, and at the end.

```
.r.r.r.r.r.r
..o..o..o..o
...b...b...b
...y...y...y
.....p.....p
...........g
```

Then, I go down each column to create my final candy order, `rorbyroprbyorrobypg`.

### Input

A string which contains the candy stash.  The input for the above example could have been:

```
oroybgrbbyrorypoprr
```

### Output

A string containing the candy reorganized into the correct order of consumption.

```
rorbyroprbyorrobypg
```

### Scoring

This is code golf.  The shortest answer in bytes wins.  Standard code-golf rules apply.

Comment: Do you just add a bigger space if the candy numbers are uneven? Lets say in this case if you had one more r candy how would the grid look like?

Comment: @Vajura yes; one more `r` would place the candy on a 84x6 board

Comment: @Vajura Like Jan Dvorak said, you would have to use a different size board for different numbers of candy.  If there were 7 `r`s, they would be placed exactly 1/7, 2/7, 3/7 etc. of the way.

Comment: Finally someone that KNOW how to eat candies.

Comment: So... basically candy dithering.

Comment: This actually comes very close to how I eat my candy. :)

Comment: What is the range of valid candy characters? The entire printable-ASCII range? Alphanumerics? In particular, it'd help me if space wasn't in that set...

Comment: @FireFly I'll say "no whitespace."

Comment: What scares me is how closely the numbers in this question match the colour proportions in actual candy. There *always* seems to be a bunch of reds and hardly any greens.

Comment: Just how greedy can one person get?  Is there a limit on the number of candies to be eaten?

Answer (score 13):

## CJam, <s>78 68 61 45 42 39 31</s> 30 bytes

```
l$:L{L\/,~}${:DM+:MD/,LD/,d/}$
```

Takes the input string via STDIN

Inspired by recursive's approach, but a little different. No need of transpose or rectangle at all!.

**How it works:**

```
l$:L                              "Sort the input line and store it in L";
    {     }$                      "Sort the string based on this code block output";
     L\/,~                        "Sort based on number of occurrences of each";
                                  "character in the full string";
            {               }$    "Sort the sorted string again";
             :DM+:M               "Store each character in D, add to M and update M";
                   D/,            "Count occurrences of D in M";
                      LD/,        "Count occurrences of D in L";
                          d/      "Sort string based on the ratio of two occurrences";
```

(Sad that CJam can no longer complete with Pyth due to need of so much bloat as syntax)

[Try it here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Comment: I don't think you need the LCM; *any* multiple should work. This should allow you to replace `{_@_@{_@\%}h;/*}` with `:`.

Comment: <facepalm> did not think of that.

Comment: Congratulations on halving your length!

Comment: I feel sarcasm in that :D

Answer (score 11):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 25

```
shCoc/NhN/zhNm>o_/zZSzdUz
```

Uses an all new algorithm, inspired by [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41100/20080).

```
(implicit)          z = input()
(implicit)          print
s                   combine list of strings into one string
 h                  first list in
  C                 matrix transpose of (e.g. first characters in first list, etc.)
   o                order_by(lambda N:
    c                        float_div(
     /NhN                              N.count(N[0]),
     /zhN                              z.count(N[0])),
    m                        map(lambda d:
     >                           slice_head(
      o                                     order_by(lambda Z:
       _/zZ                                          -1*z.count(Z),
       Sz                                            sorted(z)),
      d                                     d),
     Uz                          range(len(z))
```

Step by step:

1. First, we sorted the characters by their commonness, ties broken alphabetically. This is `o_/zZSz`. `o` is the same as Python's `sorted(<stuff>,key=<stuff>)`, with a lambda expression for the key, except it keeps it as a string.
2. Then we generate a list of the prefixes of that string, from length `len(z)` to length 1. `>` is equivalent to python's `<stuff>[<int>:]`.
3. Then, we reorder this list of prefix strings by the fractional location, 0 being the left edge and 1 being the right, of the first character of the prefix on the rectangular layout seen in the question. `/NhN` counts how many times the first character in the prefix occurs in the prefix, while `/zhN` gives the number of occurrences of the first character in the prefix in the string as a hole. This assigns each prefix being led by each character in a group a different fraction, from `1/k` for the right most occurrence of that character to `k/k` for the left most. Reordering the prefix list by this number gives the appropriate position in the layout. Ties are broken using the prior ordering, which was first by count then alphabetical, as desired.
4. Finally, we need to extract the first character from each prefix string, combine them into a single string, and print them out. Extracting the first characters is `hC`. `C` performs a matrix transpose on the list, actually `zip(*x)` in Python 3. `h` extracts the first row of the resultant matrix. This is actually the only row, because the presence of the 1 character prefix prevents any other complete rows from being formed. `s` sums the characters in this tuple into a single string. Printing is implicit.

**Test:**

```
$ pyth -c 'shCoc/NhN/zhNm>o_/zZSzdUz' <<< 'oroybgrbbyrorypoprr'
rorbyroprbyorrobypg
```

Incremental program pieces on `oroybgrbbyrorypoprr`:

```
Sub-Piece                  Output

Sz                         bbbgoooopprrrrrryyy
o_/zNSz                    rrrrrroooobbbyyyppg      (uses N because o uses N on first use.)
m>o_/zNSzdUz               ['rrrrrroooobbbyyyppg', 'rrrrroooobbbyyyppg', 'rrrroooobbbyyyppg', 'rrroooobbbyyyppg', 'rroooobbbyyyppg', 'roooobbbyyyppg', 'oooobbbyyyppg', 'ooobbbyyyppg', 'oobbbyyyppg', 'obbbyyyppg', 'bbbyyyppg', 'bbyyyppg', 'byyyppg', 'yyyppg', 'yyppg', 'yppg', 'ppg', 'pg', 'g']
oc/NhN/zhNm>o_/zZSzdUz     ['roooobbbyyyppg', 'obbbyyyppg', 'rroooobbbyyyppg', 'byyyppg', 'yppg', 'rrroooobbbyyyppg', 'oobbbyyyppg', 'pg', 'rrrroooobbbyyyppg', 'bbyyyppg', 'yyppg', 'ooobbbyyyppg', 'rrrrroooobbbyyyppg', 'rrrrrroooobbbyyyppg', 'oooobbbyyyppg', 'bbbyyyppg', 'yyyppg', 'ppg', 'g']
Coc/NhN/zhNm>o_/zZSzdUz    [('r', 'o', 'r', 'b', 'y', 'r', 'o', 'p', 'r', 'b', 'y', 'o', 'r', 'r', 'o', 'b', 'y', 'p', 'g')]
shCoc/NhN/zhNm>o_/zZSzdUz  rorbyroprbyorrobypg
```

---

Old answer:

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 34

```
ssCm*+t*u*G/zHS{-zd1]kd/zdo_/zNS{z
```

This program works by calculating how many times to replicate a certain sublist. The sub-list looks like `['', '', '', '', ... , 'r']`. The total length of this sub-list is the product of the number of occurrences of all of the other candies, which is `u*G/zHS{-zd1`. The full sublist is constructed by replicating the list of the empty string ,`]k`, that many times, then removing and element with `t` and add the candy name to the end with `+d`.

Then, this sub-list is replicated as many times as that candy is found in the input, `/zd`, ensuring each candy's list is of equal length.

Now, with this function mapped over all of the unique candies in proper sorted order (`o_/zNS{z`), we have a rectangle similar to the one in the question statement, but with empty strings instead of periods. Doing a matrix transpose (`C`) followed by two summations (`ss`) gives the final string.

Verification:

```
$ pyth programs/candy.pyth <<< 'oroybgrbbyrorypoprr'
rorbyroprbyorrobypg
```

Comment: Looks like Pyth supports encryption in the language syntax itself!

Comment: @Optimizer Encryption? What are you talking about?

Comment: Nice! I probably would have never thought to change the for loop into a map. Much cleaner.

Comment: Look at the source code. It looks like an encrypted message.

Comment: @Once you know Pyth, it makes a lot of sense. Every function used here is mnemonic, except `C`. `s` for sum, `m` for map, `t` for tail, `/` for count in, `-` for remove from, `o` for order by, etc. Unfortunately, it is quite incomprehensible for anyone who hasn't used it, you're right.

Comment: Sometimes I just can't help wondering what an entire application in such a language would look like... or even 'better' an entire world where all programmer would only program in languages like that :P

Comment: @DavidMulder Well, people have been known to write pretty complicated things in APL, which is roughly as readable.

Comment: Can you give a step by step example of the latest algorithm ? Pretty please :)

Comment: Done. I really like this golf - it has cleverness, not just short syntax.

Comment: My bad for not making it clear, but I was referring more from a point of view of taking an example and applying this algorithm step by step on it :)

Comment: @Optimizer That better?

Answer (score 6):

## Perl 5 - 62

61 code + 1 flag.

```
#!perl -n
print map/(.$)/,sort map/(.$)/*$_/$$1.~$_.$1,map++$$_.$_,/./g
```

First split the input into character array - `/./g`.

Add occurrence index to each letter leaving the counts in variables `$a`..`$z` with `map++$$_.$_`. Now the array is:

```
1o
1r
2o
1y
1b
1g
2r
2b
3b
2y
3r
3o
4r
3y
1p
4o
2p
5r
6r
```

Then convert it to a sort key concatenating: ratio `$_/$$1`, count tie breaker `~$_` and ASCII value tie breaker `$_`. This will result in (here with added spaces for clarity).

```
0.25 18446744073709551614 o
0.166666666666667 18446744073709551614 r
0.5 18446744073709551613 o
0.333333333333333 18446744073709551614 y
0.333333333333333 18446744073709551614 b
1 18446744073709551614 g
0.333333333333333 18446744073709551613 r
0.666666666666667 18446744073709551613 b
1 18446744073709551612 b
0.666666666666667 18446744073709551613 y
0.5 18446744073709551612 r
0.75 18446744073709551612 o
0.666666666666667 18446744073709551611 r
1 18446744073709551612 y
0.5 18446744073709551614 p
1 18446744073709551611 o
1 18446744073709551613 p
0.833333333333333 18446744073709551610 r
1 18446744073709551609 r
```

This can be sorted with lexicographical (default) order. In the end extract last character and print: `print map/(.$)/`

Answer (score 5):

### Python 3.x - 124 bytes

```
C=input()
print("".join(s[1]for s in sorted(enumerate(C),key=lambda
t:((C[:t[0]].count(t[1])+1+1e-10)/C.count(t[1]),t[1]))))
```

Comment: This is so much cooler of an algorithm than the rectangle method!

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, <s>123</s> <s>119</s> 118 bytes

```
f=FromCharacterCode[s=SortBy;#&@@@s[Join@@(s[Tally@ToCharacterCode@#,-Last@#&]/.{x_,n_}:>({x,#/n}&~Array~n)),{Last}]]&
```

Defines a named function `f`. Ungolfed:

```
f = FromCharacterCode[
   s = SortBy;
   # & @@@ s[
     Join @@ (
       s[
         Tally@ToCharacterCode@#,
         -Last@# &
         ] /. {x_, n_} :> ({x, #/n} &~Array~n)
       ),
     {Last}
     ]
   ] &
```

Using built-in rational types seemed like a good idea for this. Of course, this is nowhere near CJam. Basically, I'm representing the grid shown in the challenge as a list of pairs. The first thing in the pair is the character code, the second is it's position as a fraction less than or equal to 1 (the final column being 1). Having made sure that the individual characters are already in the right order, I just need to sort this stably by said fraction to get the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

### [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth) 45 <s>47 48 51</s>

This could also almost certainly be golfed further ;)

```
Ko_/zNS{zFGK~Y]*+*t/u*GHm/zdK1/zG]k]G/zG)ssCY
```

Works by building a list of lists, where each inner list is a row of empty strings and the name of the candy. This list is transposed and then the inner lists are joined followed by these lists being joined.

Thanks @isaacg for reminding me about sum!

Comment: `s` on a list of strings works as `j""`.

Answer (score 3):

**APL: 38**

```
v⌷⍨⊂⍋⌽(n/-n),⍪∊+\¨n⍴¨÷n←{≢⍵}⌸v←{⍵[⍋⍵]}
```

**Explanation:**

```
v←{⍵[⍋⍵]}    orders input string
n←{≢⍵}⌸v     counts how many times each element appears in v
∊+\¨n⍴¨÷n     makes incremental sums in each letter "group" 
⍋⌽(n/-n),⍪   appends number of elements in letter group and orders the obtained matrix
v⌷⍨⊂         orders vector v with computed indices
```

Can be tested on tryapl.org

Answer (score 2):

## R - 166 characters

```
library("plyr");s=function(a){l=table(strsplit(a,s="")[[1]]);l=ldply(l[order(-l,names(l))],function(n)data.frame(seq_len(n)/n));paste(l[order(l[[2]]),1],collapse="")}
```

ungolfed version

```
library("plyr")
s <- function(a) {
    tbl <- table(strsplit(a, split = "")[[1]])
    tbl <- tbl[order(-tbl, names(tbl))]
    tbl <- ldply(tbl, function(n) {data.frame(seq_len(n)/n)})
    paste(tbl[order(tbl[[2]]),1], collapse = "")
}
```

Explanation:

- Split into individual characters
- Tabulate number of each character
- Sort table into most frequent and then by lexical order
- Index positions for selection at 1/n, 2/n, 3/n, ... n-1/n, 1 where n is the number of candies
- Sort candy names by index (`order` is stable in sorting, so will maintain the most frequent/lexical naming order when a tie in the index, particularly important with the last candies)
- Concatenate the candy names together to make the output string

---

The matrix nature of the problem made me think R might have a shot at this, but the best literal interpretation of the algorithm I could do was 211 characters:

```
l=function(a){l=table(strsplit(a,s="")[[1]]);l=l[order(-l,names(l))];o=Reduce(`*`,l);m=matrix("",nc=o,nr=length(l));for(r in seq_along(l)){x=l[r];for(c in seq_len(x)*o/x){m[r,c]<-names(x)}};paste(m,collapse="")}
```

ungolfed:

```
l <- function(a) {
    tbl <- table(strsplit(a, split = "")[[1]])
    tbl <- tbl[order(-tbl, names(tbl))]
    o <- Reduce(`*`, tbl)
    m <- matrix("", ncol = o, nrow = length(tbl))
    for (r in seq_along(tbl)) {
        for (c in seq_len(tbl[r])*o/tbl[r]) {
            m[r,c] <- names(tbl[r])
        }
    }
    paste(m, collapse="")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 29 bytes

This is a direct translation of my [CJam answe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40914/31414)r in Pyth

```
oc/|$Y.append(N)$YN/zNo_/zZSz
```

[Try it online here](http://isaacg.scripts.mit.edu/pyth/index.py)

---

There is a rather long story behind this solution and @isaacg helped me a lot in understanding this new language.

Ideally this is the exact word to word translation of my CJam code (**17 bytes**):

```
oc/~kNN/zNo_/zZSz
```

which means:

```
o         order_by(lambda N:
 c                 div(
  /                    count(
   ~kN                       k+=N,                #Update k (initially ""), add N
   N                         N),                  #Count N in updated k
  /zN                  count(z, N)),
 o                 order_by(lambda Z:
  _                         neg(
   /zZ                          count(z, Z)),
  Sz                        sorted(z)))
```

But sadly Python does not return anything in a `+=` call, so that was not a valid Python code, thus an invalid Pyth code too as in Pyth, a lambda can only be a return statement.

Then I looked into various methods and finally found that Python's `list.append` returns a `None` value, which I can use. Making the code to be (**19 bytes**):

```
oc/|aYNYN/zNo_/zZSz
```

which means:

```
o         order_by(lambda N:
 c                 div(
  /                    count(
   |aYN                      (Y.append(N) or
    Y                         Y)                 #Update Y (initially []), append N
   N                         N),                 #Count N in updated Y
  /zN                  count(z, N)),
 o                 order_by(lambda Z:
  _                         neg(
   /zZ                          count(z, Z)),
  Sz                        sorted(z)))
```

But sadly, support of `a` (append) was removed from Pyth and the version which do has the support, does not have the support for `o`.

*Update : `a` support has been added back in Pyth now so the above 19 byte code will work in the online compiler. But since this is a new feature which was added after the OP, I am not putting it up as my score and letting the 29 byte code as my solution.*

Therefore I had to rely on raw Python in that case, making the code to be

```
o         order_by(lambda N:
 c                 div(
  /                    count(
   |$Y.append(N)$            (Y.append(N) or
    Y                         Y)                 #Update Y (initially []), append N
   N                         N),                 #Count N in updated Y
  /zN                  count(z, N)),
 o                 order_by(lambda Z:
  _                         neg(
   /zZ                          count(z, Z)),
  Sz                        sorted(z)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `d`, 20 bytes

```
ᵏ“ḶṚ:ᵂ…lD∆L÷ė←ᶻ«ᶻ×Tė
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJkIiwiIiwi4bWP4oCc4bi24bmaOuG1guKApmxE4oiGTMO3xJfihpDhtrvCq+G2u8OXVMSXIiwiIiwib3JveWJncmJieXJvcnlwb3ByciIsIjMuNC4yIl0=)

```
ᵏ“ḶṚ:ᵂ…lD∆L÷ė←⸠«r⸠×rTė­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
ᵏ“                      # ‎⁡concatenate the groups of identical items
  ḶṚ:                   # ‎⁢sort by length reversed, push two copies
     ᵂ…                 # ‎⁣vectorized head of the bottom copy
       lD               # ‎⁤push three copies of vectorized length
         ∆L             # ‎⁢⁡least common multiple
           ÷ė           # ‎⁢⁢reciprocal of length divided by LCM, gives the length of one candy+space
             ←          # ‎⁢⁣rotate stack left once
              ⸠ r       # ‎⁢⁤zip  candy types and chunk length and reduce by
               «        # ‎⁣⁡prepending spaces to match chunk length
                 ⸠ r    # ‎⁣⁢zip chunks and original vectorized lengths and reduce by
                  ×     # ‎⁣⁣multiplication
                    Tė  # ‎⁣⁤transpose and remove whitespace
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: I don't know Vyxal but I am fairly sure you can knock off some bytes by taking my J approach rather than using LCM.  Typically Vyxal translations of J are about half the size or less, I've noticed.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 28 bytes

```
(/:&;<@(%@#(*,.[)#\)/.~)@/:~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYq7DsIwDAB3vsKiokn6cJhNQRZITIiBtRSkoLbA4spblv56KMPdcvdNazQD7AkMVLAFWqgRTrfLOVlP@a5hu@HMFhW2Lrs7j7NjT3Nyq@sRoaXSc8XWlh6wKLFzD3rOdeca/iBnPeaHbtW/3gJGRUNUmRaLqoQ4jQZqggGMqMQwavh3jdPyqEk/)

- `/:~` As a pre-process step, sort input to ensure that in cases like `bbb` and `yyy`, where each group has equal size, ties are broken using ascii order.
- Now we're going to come up with a "score" for each item, so we can solve the whole problem in a single sort...
- `(...)/.~` For each group of items...

  - `%@#` Calculate the reciprocal of the group size
  - `#\` And `1 2 ... n` where `n` is the group size
  - `*` Multiply those two together to determine the major sorting score
  - `,.[` And zip that with the reciprocal of the group size, which will be the minor sorting score.  Ie, if two items from different groups have the same major score, the one in the group with more items comes first.
- `/:&;` Sort the pre-processed input using those scores.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>15</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
{ΣKg}Σˆ¯y¢Iy¢/
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/@txi7/Tac4tPtx1aX3lokScQ6///n1@UX5mUXpSUVFmUX1RZkF9QVAQA)

**Explanation:**

Step 1: Sort the character-groups from longest to shortest, with lowest ASCII codepoint first for ties:

```python
{      # Sort the characters in the (implicit) input by their ASCII codepoints
 Σ  }  # Then sort it further by:
  K    #  Remove the current character from the (implicit) input-string
   g   #  Pop and push the length of the remaining characters
```

[Try just step 1.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/@txi7/Ta///zi/Irk9KLkpIqi/KLKgvyC4qKAA)

Step 2: Sort them further by their progressively updating counts:

```python
Σ      # Sort it further by:
 ˆ     #  Pop and add the current character to the global array (empty by default)
 ¯     #  Push the global array
  y¢   #  Count the amount of times the current character occurs in it
 I     #  Push the input-string
  y¢   #  Count the amount of times the current character occurs in it as well
    /  #  Divide those two counts
       # (after which the sorted string is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 99 bytes

```javascript
x=>[...x].map(A=c=>A[c]=-~A[c]).map((c,i)=>[c/A[u=x[i]],''.padEnd(c),u]).sort().map(x=>x[2]).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzLCsMgFER/JTsVEgPdG8iiXyFC1DwwpF65JkU3/XVr2s0MczjMrt86WnTh7DzMS1lFSWKQnPOk@EsHOgorhlFaJbrPXexHqW0dq57tR3mJJJ1SLSE86PnpZ2pZe1UxAp7079fPJB@V7eD8NBULPsKx8AM2ulICCNlsaExGwBwgIBLGmr5v6r5hqAmIYHLYyhc)